# Mouse clicking when removing finger

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I have an annoying problem. Whenever i use the mouse, when i remove my finger, the cursor have some sort of timer, and it clicks after a few seconds. When i remove my finger, the cursor gets orange, and after some time, it clicks. 
How can i turn this feature off? I have tried fooling around in both systems settings and the gpoint app. 
Anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I found out that typing "mousetweaks -s" shuts down this funktion.. but every time the computer has been shut off or on standby, it restarts. How can i make this go away permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your comment!

The command you suggest worked for me too, and helped me to find how to fix it. I am still puzzled why this problem started.

### Here is a solution:

Click  **System Settings -> Universal Access -> Pointing and Clicking**
Switch **Hover Click** to **Off**.
That's all!

Here is how I knew where to look.
I assumed that if this mousetweaking starts after restart, there is some setting that triggers it. Who might want such an odd behavior? 
I looked for it with various grep commands. This one is a winner:
    grep -r mousetweak .*
It founds that file *~ /.local/share/gsettings-data-convert* mentions it. It must be a Gnome setting. So I digged Gnome help for a while and found it :)